# Calculating a statistic for multiple studies in R

Tags: r, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a data set in which I want to apply several tests such as KS two sample. So I'm trying to find an algorithm which can apply the KS two sample test to all samples. The basic idea is:

Lets say I have a data set with these observations:

```
       1 2 3 4
Study1 9 1 2 6
Study2 5 6 7 8
Study3 4 3 2 1
Study4 8 7 6 5
Study5 1 3 5 7
Study6 2 4 6 8
Study7 1 3 6 9
Study8 2 4 7 1
Study9 2 5 8 4
Study10 3 6 8 5
```

I could apply the KS test to each and every study with the following:

```
ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[1,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[1,])))
ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[1,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[2,])))
ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[1,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[3,])))
                                   ...
ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[1,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[10,])))
ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[2,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[1,])))
                                   ...
ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[10,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[10,])))
```

This would result in 10x10 p-values and my aim is to use this as a measure of distance.

So I'm looking for an algorithm which can run a KS test for n x n samples and then output the p-values in a n x n matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `outer`:

```
outer(1:10, 1:10, Vectorize(function(i,j) {ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[i,])),as.numeric(as.vector(df[j,])))$p.value}))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 100] do not match the length of object [500]
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

Comment: what are the warnings?

Comment: All 50 are the same:

`Warning messages:
1: In ks.test(as.numeric(as.vector(df[i, ])), as.numeric(as.vector(df[j,  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties`

Comment: ah. apologies - you should select the p-value. I modified the answer

Comment: Thanks so much! Although the errors are still there it works very well

Comment: I believe the warnings are purely because of the data, it might be something worth checking. good luck!